# Swift - Override default encoding/decoding

Tags: swift, jsonencoder

`CGSize` is encoded to an array by default. I would like to encode it to `[String: Float]` (i.e. `["width": 10, "height": 20]`). Is there a way to override the default encoding/decoding behavior? Of course, as a workaround, I can define my own `Dimension` type and use that instead. I am just curious to know.

Comment: What encoder you are using?

Comment: you probably meant `{"width": 10, "height": 20}`

Comment: @LeoDabus I see the comment is now gone, but for posterity: I wouldn't recommend that last approach (I alluded to it in my answer but didn't want to spell out the details) — it's really fragile, and works only in your own module; other modules won't necessarily see that method (esp. modules you have a dependency on), and you can silently get mixed encodings.

Comment: @ItaiFerber ok thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no supported way to outright override the encoding format for a given type you don't own; there are hacks that you can apply to override some types within your own module, but they're fragile and not worth employing.

If you use a 3rd-party encoder/decoder combo that isn't `Foundation.JSONEncoder`/`Foundation.JSONDecoder`, it may offer an override facility similar to encoding/decoding strategies supported by Foundation, but that is dependent on the tools you're using.

The "official" way to do this would be to either wrap `CGSize` in a type you do own (as you suggest) and implement `init(from:)`/`encode(to:)` there, or override `init(from:)`/`encode(to:)` for all of the types that use `CGSize` (but this can get pretty tedious).

Comment: Thanks! A quick followup question, what's the advantage of wrapping it instead of just replacing it with something like `{width: Double, height: Double}`? Is it to avoid duplicate implementations that becomes a bigger issue for types not as simple as `CGSize`?

Comment: Yep, exactly. `CGSize` might not see a huge win, but a type like [`CGAffineTransform`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgaffinetransform) is a bit more annoying to recreate. The other benefit is interoperability with other APIs that take or vend `CGSize` so you don't have to recreate them to take `Dimension`.